# Is it possible to set a separate color scheme for the popup of CtrlP plugin?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

Thought it is my first time ever to encounter vimscript, I've checked the plugin code. It has the following lines of code:

```
fu! ctrlp#init(type, ...)
    if exists('s:init') || s:iscmdwin() | retu | en
    let [s:ermsg, v:errmsg] = [v:errmsg, '']
    let [s:matches, s:init] = [1, 1]
    cal s:Reset(a:0 ? a:1 : {})
    noa cal s:Open()
    cal s:SetWD(a:0 ? a:1 : {})
    gal s:MapNorms()
    cal s:MapSpecs()
    cal ctrlp#syntax()
    cal ctrlp#setlines(s:settype(a:type))
    cal s:SetDefTxt()
    cal s:BuildPrompt(1)
    if s:keyloop | cal s:KeyLoop() | en
endf
```

if I put `colorscheme atom` or something like that inside the function, it changes the color scheme of the whole buffer instead of just changing the color scheme of the popup. Is there any way to configure CtrlP to use a separate color scheme? Of course, I didn't intend to put configuration to the plugin code, so I'm also looking for a solution that enables me to put the setting into my `.vimrc`, for example something using `autocmd`.

Comment: It isn't possible unless the ctrlp plugin specifies its own color color groups.  Color schemes are basically just vim scripts which only specify colors for different color groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`+1`** for looking at the source and *actually* trying something.

**`-1`** for not looking at [the plugin's documentation](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L1181):

```
Highlighting:~
* For the CtrlP buffer:
    CtrlPNoEntries : the message when no match is found (Error)
    CtrlPMatch     : the matched pattern (Identifier)
    CtrlPLinePre   : the line prefix '>' in the match window
    CtrlPPrtBase   : the prompt's base (Comment)
    CtrlPPrtText   : the prompt's text (|hl-Normal|)
    CtrlPPrtCursor : the prompt's cursor when moving over the text (Constant)

* In extensions:
    CtrlPTabExtra  : the part of each line that's not matched against (Comment)
    CtrlPBufName   : the buffer name an entry belongs to (|hl-Directory|)
    CtrlPTagKind   : the kind of the tag in buffer-tag mode (|hl-Title|)
    CtrlPqfLineCol : the line and column numbers in quickfix mode (Comment)
    CtrlPUndoT     : the elapsed time in undo mode (|hl-Directory|)
    CtrlPUndoBr    : the square brackets [] in undo mode (Comment)
    CtrlPUndoNr    : the undo number inside [] in undo mode (String)
    CtrlPUndoSv    : the point where the file was saved (Comment)
    CtrlPUndoPo    : the current position in the undo tree (|hl-Title|)
    CtrlPBookmark  : the name of the bookmark (Identifier)

Statuslines:~
* Highlight groups:
    CtrlPMode1 : 'file' or 'path' or 'line', and the current mode (Character)
    CtrlPMode2 : 'prt' or 'win', 'regex', the working directory (|hl-LineNr|)
    CtrlPStats : the scanning status (Function)
```

***Edit***

Take a look at your favorite colorscheme, if it is competently written, you should find a bunch of lines looking like this one:

```
hi Whatever ctermbg=235 ctermfg=250 guibg=#262626 guifg=#bcbcbc cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

What you need to do is simple:

1. copy one of those lines,
2. change the highlight group name from `Whatever` to `CtrlPNoEntries`,
3. adjust the color values to suit your taste,
4. repeat.

If you want your colorscheme to be standalone, you will need to define all those CtrlP highlights in a separate file that will be loaded like any other plugin but late in the startup process:

```
~/.vim/after/plugin/mycolorscheme.vim
```

Comment: I did look at the documentation, I just have no idea how vim works, so I didn't realize that this is the important part. That's why I decided to look at the source, because it shows at least, how the plugin works and what it does. Thanks for pointing to the important part. If my understanding is correct, I *can't* set a separate color scheme for the popup, but I can override the color of each highlight group independently from the color scheme, one-by-one, right? With the `highlight Group value` command. Is that the only way?

Comment: Please see my edit. Some plugins like Airline or Lightline have theming built-in so it is possible to write a specific colorscheme that will apply only to specific features of a specific plugin. CtrlP doesn't so you basically have two solutions: edit your colorscheme (you'll need to do that again, even if it's only a matter of copy/pasting, next time you find a better colorscheme) or put the needed highlight definitions in a separate plugin (which you'll do only once, hopefully).